# Attribute “datetime” not allowed on element “span” at this point

Tags: html

I ran my webpage through validator.w3.org and it came up with three errors.  I am using Schema.org/WebPage for reference.

Attribute “datetime” not allowed on element “span” at this point.

Anyone understand what they mean

```
<span class="alignright">
<br/>Last Modified : <span itemprop="dateModified" datetime="20-06-2022T20:39:45">20th June 2022</span><br/>
Date Published : <span itemprop="dateCreated" datetime="16-04-2014T10:38:32">16th April 2014</span>
</span>
```

I can't see anything wrong with this and the error is not clear.

Comment: I am just curious, what is the purpose of  `datetime` attribute in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`datetime`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_time_datetime.asp) a valid attribute for [`<time>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_time.asp), `<ins>`, and `<del>` tags which would be semantically perfect for that layout.

```html
<span class="alignright">
<br/>Last Modified : 
<time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="2022-06-20T20:39:45">20th June 2022</time><br/>
Date Published : 
<time itemprop="dateCreated" datetime="2014-04-16T10:38:32">16th April 2014</time>
</span>
```

Comment: I took your advice and now get " Bad value “20-06-2022T20:39:45” for attribute “datetime” on element “time”: The literal did not satisfy the time-datetime format." , do you have any recommendation please ?

Comment: The details on proper formatting is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_time_datetime.asp). I'll update answer as well.

Comment: Thats perfect, its passed the W3.org validator, I needed to swap yyyy and dd around the other way.  That works.  Don't anyone tell you you're not awesome....